# I am using vue-date-pick for a calender input. But I want to disable all the previous dates expect today an upcoming dates

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vuejs3

In the docs of the respective library(https://dbrekalo.github.io/vue-date-pick/), there is a section to address this issue but it's for disabling upcoming dates. Please help,
Here I am giving the code-snippet of the docs solution (I want to disable the past dates)

```js
<template>
    <date-pick
        v-model="date"
        :isDateDisabled="isFutureDate"
    ></date-pick>
</template>

<script>
import DatePick from 'vue-date-pick';
export default {
    components: {DatePick},
    data: () => ({
        date: ''
    }),
    methods: {
        isFutureDate(date) {
            const currentDate = new Date();
            return date > currentDate;
        }
    }
};
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
<date-pick
    v-model="date"
    :isDateDisabled="isPastDate"
></date-pick>
```

```js
methods: {
    isPastDate(date) {
        const yesterday = new Date().setDate(new Date().getDate() - 1);
        return date < yesterday;
    }
}
```

Comment: But it's disabling the current date also, I want to make all past date disable not the current one

Comment: thanks a lot but it should be "-" not "+". anyways you saved my life